# Winding Numbers and Simply Connected Sets

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Suppose $D$ if a path connected open subset of $\mathbb C$ so that the winding number of any $x$ in $\mathbb C -D$ with respect to any loop lying in $D$ is 0. Why does this imply that every loop lying in $D$ is null homotopic ie $D$ is simply connected?

Comment: I think it is but 2 others have voted to close, probably because you show no work or context.

Comment: it’s a legitimate question. i have no idea why it should be voted as closed …

Comment: It takes a whole semester of complex analysis to prove this. You need to prove 1) the homological version of the Cauchy integral formula, and 2) the Riemann mapping theorem.